# Why to use Sitecore form over WFFM

Tags: wffm, sitecore-forms

Why should we go with Sitecore form if WFFM form has more features?

For example sitecore from has only below 6 actions where wffm has lot many actions

Trigger Goal, Trigger Campaign Activity, Trigger Outcome, Redirect to Page, Save Data and Send Email Campaign

Comment: Think if WFFM like the Titanic.

Answer (score 5):

It's a simple answer.  Because WFFM will eventually become obsolete and eventually not be included or supported with Sitecore anymore.  I believe the plan is that Sitecore Forms will eventually contain all the same features that WFFM currently includes.

Comment: Dylan is absolutely spot on. Later down the road when Sitecore 9 Forms starts gaining a lot traction you will want to take advantage, and then you are stuck converting all your forms to Sitecore Forms. At that point, it might not be a big deal with a converter, but you never know. If I were in your shoes, I recommend starting with Sitecore 9 Forms now as they are not that hard at all to learn. Here are some best practices: https://blogs.perficient.com/sitecore/2018/03/30/best-practices-on-sitecore-9-forms-for-development-teams/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Dylan said:

1. Sitecore Forms comes OOTB with Sitecore Platform hence the additional efforts of installation as well as upgrade can be avoided.
2. Multi-step form creation is not possible in WFFM which can be achieved in Sitecore Forms OOTB
3. Sitecore Forms UI is much more intuitive comparing to WFFM like drag and drop functionality etc
4. You can save Form as a template using Sitecore Forms
5. Sitecore Forms is much more easier in maintaining Forms items with lots of features available OOTB like searching/sorting on Forms, Overview and Performance Tab etc